# WAMP 403 forbidden error when using 'glob()'

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp, glob

I'm trying to make PHP grab the paths to all images in a folder (and then select one at random), but I keep getting a `403 - forbidden` warning.

I tried using both `glob()` and `scandir()`, as well as trying the path directly in the browser.

Here is my code (using `glob()`) -

```
$directory = plugins_url('images/backgrounds', __FILE__);
if(is_dir($directory)) :
    $backgrounds = glob($directory . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
endif;
```

I'm using WAMP and developing locally, so I can't see any reason why Apache wouldn't have access to the folder in question.

The `$directory` is correct, so it's not that it doesn't exist that is causing a problem (a 404 error is returned if I deliberatly alter the path to one I know doesn't exist).

I am preventing indexing via `.htaccess` but I have since removed this line and it made no difference.

Can anyone please suggest what I might check to try and fix this issue? Thanks.

---

## Edit

I should add that my PHP and Apache logs seem to not be logging this event.

Comment: Are the rights to the files themsleves correct?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. I'm developing locally on Windows, so the Apache server should have permission to read anything it desires. It was when I move to my test environment (LAMP) that I was expecting issues, as the permissions are much more explicit. Thanks.

Comment: ...although curiously I do have permission to view some other folders, yet checking the `Security` tab suggests that the permissions are exactly the same.

Comment: doesn't `plugins_url` return URL and not path?

Comment: It does. Good point, I didn't take it to accound that PHP my not be able to translate. I'll try and get the path and report back...

Comment: @NikhilSupekar - you are a winner! Thanks for the nudge, that was the problem.  If you add that as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: @DavidGard Sometimes we just need to think outside the box! :)
and Thanks! I will write the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have used - `plugins_url` which looks like a Wordpress function which will return a URL.

But you have to pass a file path to the `glob` function.

So you can use `plugin_dir_path()`, a wordpress function to get absolute path of plugin directory which can be used in `glob` function.